# CSS parallax - how to set height and scroll range

Tags: html, css

I've been playing around with [Keith Clark's CSS parallax](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) and it's pretty awesome.

What I can't figure out is, how is the total height of the scrollable area being controlled, the placement of the parallax layers, or the range of how far they can be scrolled.

For example, view this example:  https://jsfiddle.net/evemzodb/

html:

```
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back c1">
    back c1
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base c2">
    base c2
  </div>
   <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--deep c3">
    deep c3
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
.parallax__layer--deep {
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}

.c1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.c2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.c3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The total height of the scrollable area appears to be 200vh.  How is this being determined?  Is this a result of the scale and translateZ attributes?  Similarly, what is causing the spacing between the .base and .back div?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the total height is simply if the layer is at all visible on screen then the whole layer is rendered, and a layers maximum size is 100vh therefore it's logical the total height is actually nearer (but just under) 300vh. for below, on screen, and above.

Comment: The transform attribute property handles the "depth" of the "layer" with the Scale factor which is an inverse (scale 1 is full screen, scale 2 is half screen etc.)

Comment: That doesn't describe what's in the example though.  300vh would make sense - but the base layer in scrolling in a space that only appears to have 200vh (in the sense that there is 100vh below it when scrolled all the way up).

For the .deep layer, there is only ~30vh empty space below the div when scrolled up.

It seems like they should be consistent... I'm trying to figure out the rules governing them since they actually are not.

Comment: It is a 3dimensional space, using a 2D (Orthographic) camera angle.This means the distance away from the camera does not effect the "scale* of the subject object (the background), only the distance *between* the item and the camera. The camera is the browser.

Comment: I'm not confused with the general theory of how the 3rd space is being presented.  I want to identify the specific attributes that are controlling these layers and the space.  Using standard positioning and height attributes aren't changing the behavior in normal ways.